# Add textview to layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

**I cant put a textview above my buttons without having my buttons move...How can I fix this?**

Been stuck on this for 4 hours...Which is sad because I'm trying to add a textview on my layout...

I have a layout with 4 buttons in the center. I simply want to add a textview above the four buttons, like illustrated here (TextView should be in the place of the red) :

[image]

The drag and drop in the XML layout view will not work when I place the textview above the buttons. It just dis centers the buttons. I also tried doing what [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887815/android-how-do-i-position-views-in-an-offset-relative-to-the-center-top-bottom) answer suggested, **but then the anchor view itself would not be positioned in the center!**

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.me.circleswithmap.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bluesquare" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/greensquare" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/redsquare" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/Purple"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Red"
        android:background="@drawable/purplesquare" />



    NEED SOME TEXTVIEW ALSO! WHENEVER I ADD ONE, IT DISCENTERS THE REST OF THE BUTTONS!


</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do to tackle this problem? Why is it so difficult? Should I not use Relative Layout? How can I stop this from being relative to each other?

Thanks so much,

NullPointerException

Comment: You could put a FrameLayout as the outermost layout element, and put the RelativeLayout and your TextView inside that element.

Comment: @1615903 How do I move my current code into a new layout then? Feel free to post an answer. Thanks for your reply :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.example.ruchir.circleswithmap.MainActivity"
                android:id="@+id/layout">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/text_container"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:text="pruebaskjahlkdjahslk"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Green"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blue"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Red"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blue"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Purple"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Red"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Red"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Landscape orientation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context="com.example.me.circleswithmap.MainActivity"
                android:id="@+id/layout">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/text_container"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="20:00"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_container"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Green"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blue"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Red"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blue"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blue"/>

        <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/Purple"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Red"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Red"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Also, how do I get the four buttons centers in the middle of the screen? I tried `android:gravity = "center"` in the relative layout, but it did nothing

Comment: Copy my answer "as is". They are centered.

Comment: Okay, its working. So, without the background, there is a margin between the buttons...that margin goes away after I add the background. Is there a way to keep that margin? http://snag.gy/ew2nD.jpg

Comment: It is hard to answer that without  having the background drawables. Try adding some margin to each ImageButton

Comment: Okay, so I'm going to mark you best answer and like your post once I get this. How do I actually place the four buttons in the center when I have landscape orientation. Again, the layout is not dragging.

Comment: Have you tried the same layout for landscape orientation? It is working for me. The buttons are centered.

Comment: Really? I want enough space at the bottom for an ad...But don't have that space. Here is the layout: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07a73b1931712f47fc55

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97848/discussion-between-nullpointerexception-and-bigdestroyer).

Comment: Now I want to put the textView on the side of the four squares...How do I do that? I tried doing the linear layout method, but then, the four buttons just move again.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to help me? Or give me a suggestion? That would be great. Thanks

Comment: He has no longer solved your question. If you have more doubts write more questions.

Comment: @Sapikelio I did, but it got marked duplicate. I don't know what to do now. `bigdestroyer` is not responding anymore, because only reason he posted the answer was for rep.

Comment: @bigdestroyer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286727/add-textview-next-to-buttons-not-a-duplicate

Answer (score 0):

A simple and quick solution could be to use two layouts: keep the `RelativeLayout` and embed it in a vertical `LinearLayout`. Then you can just add the `TextView` to the `LinearLayout` before the `RelativeLayout`.

Caution: using multiple layers of Layouts can hurt performance, so don't overdo it. Two layouts shouldn't hurt though.

Comment: How do I move my current layout into the LinearLayout?

Comment: I would just do that manually in the XML file, I don't use the wysiwyg designer much. The easiest way might be to change the types of the tags you have right now from <RelativeLayout> to <LinearLayout> and then drag and drop a new RelativeLayout in the designer. Don't forget to change your layout properties accordingly (for both layouts)! EDIT: Oh and don't forget to move your buttons to the new RelativeLayout, of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the buttons inside a layout and then place a textview above it and tell the new layout to be below the text view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ruchir.circleswithmap.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview111"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/password_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/textview111"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Purple"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Red"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this should do the trick, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It will work in all size of devices but you have to take of text  size of left `TextView` dynamically. `TextView` text size should be small according device density. hope it will help.!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#010101"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.ruchir.circleswithmap.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timetext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="20:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#fbfafa"
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="50:00"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#fbfafa"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Blue"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Purple"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Green"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Red"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Red"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```