# How to align view by center point?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create this layout

[image]

Then I found this

[Android - How do I position views in an offset relative to the center/top/bottom (etc.) of their parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887815/android-how-do-i-position-views-in-an-offset-relative-to-the-center-top-bottom)

So I created this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/square"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/square"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/square"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/circle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But the layout margin does not have any effect

The output is same to

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/square"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/square"
    android:src="@mipmap/circle" />
```

How to align a view's center point to certain point of other view?

Comment: is center in horizontal and vertical working in your code? try it

Comment: Place the circle inside the square, then move up and left a full radius

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have done one example, my be it help to you

please check following code with output

```
<FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/FrameMove"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearFramelayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/frame_drawable"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="-50dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtMove"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end|top"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_close_white"/>

            </FrameLayout>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This answer is difficult to apply in my current layout, but finally I inspired from this answer, I just need to set android:layout_marginRight="-25dp", then the problem is solved, so this is still a useful answer

Answer (score 0):

One option is giving the square a margin Top and margin Left that is equal to the radius of the circle. Let both elements have attribute`alignParentLeft=true`

Answer (score 0):

if you know the width and height of your circle image then this could be easy 
you need to use a framelayout and give left and top margin to the square half the width and height of a circle